# Power to 2 and 3 from inside TS file for p-table

Tags: angular, primeng, p-table

I have a p-table called cols:

**TS file:**

```
public cols: any[];
    
   public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.cols = [
      { field: 'length', header: 'Length (m)' },
      { field: 'width', header: 'Width (m)' },
      { field: 'height', header: 'Height (m)' },
      { field: 'area', header: 'Area (m2)' },
      { field: 'volume', header: 'Volume (m3)' },
    ];
  }
```

**HTML file:**

```
<p-table [value]="cols">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let col of cols">
                {{col.header}}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-col>
        <tr>
            <td *ngFor="let col of cols">
                {{col[col.field]}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Area and Volume are respectively in square meter and cubic meter. How should I **modify Area (m2)** and **Volume (m3)** so that they show **m to the power 2 and 3** in correct format?

I have already tried  tags, but it did not help:

```
 this.cols = [
      ....
      { field: 'area', header: 'Area (m<sup>2</sup>)' },
      { field: 'volume', header: 'Volume (m<sup>3</sup>)' },
    ];
```

EDIT:
Please note that my issue is not how to populate the results (numbers), rather how to show the **headers** correctly.
To make it clear what I mean by correct and incorrect formats see this:
[image]

Right now the exponents in the **headers** are shown in incorrect format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular HTML binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-html-binding)

Comment: @KaustubhBadrike No. It has nothing to do with my question.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

ts

```js
this.cols = [
      ....
      { field: 'area', header: 'Area (m<sup>2</sup>)' },
      { field: 'volume', header: 'Volume (m<sup>3</sup>)' },
];
```

html

```html
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-col>
    <tr>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let col of cols">
            <td [innerhtml]="col[col.field]"></td>
        </ng-container>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
```

Same as : https://stackoverflow.com/a/34424375/8944414
[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-69jrwi)

Comment: You suggested this link before, but as I said it does not answer my question.

My issue is NOT how to show the numbers (results), rather how to show the "headers" in correct format. See the the updated version of the question.

Comment: That link **does** answer your question, because the concept remains the same. [Here's a working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-69jrwi). Instead of expecting a complete implementation, try understanding existing answers first to then apply the concept to your particular use-case.